multiGPU training with sementation_models and keras
I want to use multiple GPUs to train a model, because there is not enough memory in a single GPU card for my training.
To do this, I tried following these instructions: Multi-GPU distributed training with TensorFlow
I an trying to do this using segmentation_models, and the training function is as follows:
def run_training(BACKBONE, n_classes, activation, metrics, EPOCHS, X_train, X_test, y_train_cat, y_test_cat):
    # Create a MirroredStrategy.
    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
    print(‘Number of devices: {}’.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

    # Open a strategy scope and create/restore the model
    with strategy.scope():
        model = sm.Unet(BACKBONE, encoder_weights='imagenet', classes=n_classes, activation=activation)
        weights = [0,.1,.45,.45]
        loss = weighted_categorical_crossentropy(weights)
        
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss, metrics=metrics)
    #model1.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(), loss=loss, metrics=metrics)

        history=model.fit(X_train, 
          y_train_cat,
          batch_size=4, 
          epochs=EPOCHS,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test_cat))

        return history, model

Where BACKBONE is one of the backbones supported by segmentation_models.
This code worked when I was not trying the distributed processing strategy. However, then I run it with the distributed processing strategy, it runs, and goes through the training, but I get invalid results.
Here is an example of the IOU vs epochs output.

When not using distributed processing, the validation IOU rises to around 0.5 or 0.6.
In other cases, I saw the training and val IOU go to 0.5 or 0.6667 after a few epochs and stay constant .
What am I doing wrong, and can I use the segmentation_models package with multiple GPUs?
Additional information:
I ran the training with two GPUs and batch size = 8.  This appeared to run, and produced the following result:

Then I ran the same training set with one GPU and batch size = 1 (because larger batch sizes result in an out of memory (OOM) error)
Here is the result:

With 2-GPUs, batch sizes of 2 and 4 produce results similar to the first figure above. With one GPU, I could only test with a batch size = 1, due to memory limitations.
I will add here the weighted loss function that I am using.
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def weighted_categorical_crossentropy(weights):
    """
    From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62203263/sparse-annotation-in-u-net
    
    A weighted version of keras.objectives.categorical_crossentropy
    By assigning one of the classes a weight of zero, it is possible to ignore that class.
    This allows partial annotation. Typically, class zero is the area that is not annotated,
    and weigh(class=0)=0.
    
    Variables:
        weights: numpy array of shape (C,) where C is the number of classes
    
    Usage example:
        weights = np.array([0.5,2,10]) # Class one at 0.5, class 2 twice the normal weights, class 3 10x.
        loss = weighted_categorical_crossentropy(weights)
        model.compile(loss=loss,optimizer='adam')
        
    Last modifed: 08 April 2024
    """
    
   # weights = K.variable(weights)
    weights = tf.Variable(weights)
        
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        # scale predictions so that the class probas of each sample sum to 1
        y_pred /= K.sum(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        # clip to prevent NaN's and Inf's
        y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1 - K.epsilon())
        # calc
        loss = y_true * K.log(y_pred) * weights
        loss = -K.sum(loss, -1)
        return loss
    
    return loss

Update: the following two steps improved the result.

Reduced learning rate to 0.0005 (1/2 of previous rate)

Added gradient clipping, as in:
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)
optimizer = tf.keras.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer(optimizer)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)


The result is:

I do not know why training IOU drops, while the validation IOU stays at its plateau. The resulting model worked well.
I need to understand better what is going on with the training IOU, and to experiment with different conditions (LR, optimizer, etc).
I have limited ability to play with batch size because each card has only 12GB of GPU memory. Currently batch size is 3.

How many GPUs are you using when you use the MirroredStrategy? This is a pretty common phenomenon, where a network finds a bad local minimum and crashes. It often has to do with the training data. Make sure all of your batches are full, make sure your batches can be distributed across the GPU's.  Usually the batch size errors happen sooner, but I've recently seen it affect a loss function.

I can add that if I use only one GPU, as in
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(["GPU:0"])
then the training works properly.
The same code with both GPUs as in
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(["GPU:0","GPU:1"])
fails as above.

You'll probably need to inspect the loss per batch. You go from 1 gpu to 2 gpus. Your batch size is 4. Does your data have a number of samples divisible by 4? If you go from 1 gpu to 2 gpus, does it still crash when you set the batch size to 8? What about using 1 gpu with a batchsize of 2?

See edit above . I added the outputs of a run with 2 GPUs and batch size = 8,
and 1 GPU with batch size =1.

Are you saying it works with a batch size of 8, but not with 2 and 4? What is "the figure above" all of the figures are above. What is your training data size? Maybe you could reproduce the problem with a publicly available dataset, that way if somebody is inclined to help they could try it out for themselves?

Sometimes it works with batch=8, but the results are not the same as with a single GPU and generally worse (lower IOU).
The "figure above" is the first figure in the post, as opposed to the group of four plots that follow.
Here is a link to the dataset:
https://drive.proton.me/urls/1HPPW7XJSM#xkrZp5tgpiFu
There are plant images and corresponding label images. The classes are
1,2,3 with 0 being unlabeled pixels. I use a weighted crossentropy loss to give the 0 pixels no weight.
Later I will ass a README file to document the dataset.
